# Flutter HomePage too many widgets getting build and creating http error sometimes

Tags: flutter

I am creating ecommerce app in Flutter and have made multiple widgets to show on HomePage. Issue is that as there are around 5-8 idgets that gets build while app is opened, I am having issue that too many server request are sent at the time of opening app as each widget is build based on separate json data.
This also takes few seconds before data is shown on app.

Is there a way to load all widgets faster and avoid too many http request as i get http error on backend sometimes when too many http requests are sent.

My Home Screen

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            CarouselSliderList(),
            Banner1Slot(),
            TopCategoriesList(),
            HotProducts(),
            TopCategoriesList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I am using below method to call API requests. As there are many widgets, multiple CircularProgressIndicator() shows on screen, I want only 1 ProgressIndicator for all widgets.

```
Future<List<CarouselSlider>> getCarouselSlider(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client.get('https://androidapp.factory2homes.com/api/carouselslider');
  return compute(parseCarouselSlider, response.body);
}


List<CarouselSlider> parseCarouselSlider(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<CarouselSlider>((json) => CarouselSlider.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

```
class CarouselSliderList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TopCategoriesListState createState() => _TopCategoriesListState();
}

class _TopCategoriesListState extends State<CarouselSliderList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<CarouselSlider>>(
      future: getCarouselSlider(http.Client()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? CarouselSliderBanner(
                carouselSlider: snapshot.data,
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                ),
              );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error message? Also, how are you calling these http requests, inside initState? If you can show a little part of your sub componentes can help as well.

Comment: You can fetch all the data together one time only when the app is initiate?

Comment: I have edited code with method used for calling http requests

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a repository with a method that uses `Future.wait([])` and runs a list of Futures where you can get them all in one result, and then use those to build out your widgets by passing the data down to them